# Unable to run any queries on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I am trying to run a query on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq). Not logged into it results in an output of

```
{"captcha":true}
```

instead of the actual [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) coming up.

To be specific, it's coming on [this question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101907/posts-with-titles-of-3-words-or-less).

Comment: I was able to run the query logged off.  Captcha showed up and it went through.  Running off of FF 4.0.

Comment: if you've run the query before, it shows the cached results. Running in Incognito /Private Mode / Porn mode results in the above message coming all the time @JeffMercado

Comment: Hmm, oddly, running in private mode through a proxy for me didn't show the captcha at all.  Even tweaking the query to make sure it wasn't cached still ran fine.  I'll probably have to try this again when the captcha wears off.

Comment: Just retried again in private through a proxy, could not reproduce.

Comment: Runs fine on Chrome+Win7 while logged in. Captcha showed up only the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was fixed a while back.